# Microservice - Definition of variables in different layers. Design best practices

Tags: java, rest, design-patterns

I have two layers:

1. API: exposes the different resources and objects for consumers. (jar)
2. Service : contains all the business logic.

I have objects, constants and enums that I am repeating them since I use them in both layers

So, in the API i can have one object like

```
class MyObject {
      MyEnum enum;
      ...
      //getters and setters
}
```

and

```
 enum MyEnum {
       ONE, TWO
 }
```

In my service layer i have my MyObjectDTO (with some business variables that are exclusive to the service layer) and the **same** MyEnum.

I have repeated objects in both layers (with some differences but not at the enums or constants).

The question is: Is there a better approach?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is usually good practice to separate your read and write DTO's. Look up on CQRS. This way when your write side changes, your read may or may not need to change. Its nicely decoupled. Also, if you want to distribute your write DTO's then you can do so in a separate library without affecting read DTOs.